# Can you Man-in-the-Middle HTTP Requests with Control over the Static Files

Tags: javascript, networking, browser

I am currently working on a project which involves re-serving our client's websites from a cached version of their site. We currently do this by recording all the network traffic made when traversing the site, and saving that in our cache system. Then when we distribute the site, we replace all of the request URLs with a request to our servers. For example, a request to `https://www.google.com/` would end up as `https://www.our-server.com/reroute?url=https://www.google.com/`.

This method works for most cases, but it misses a some where URLs are not in plaintext (created from variables, or dynamically generated). We realize this will be an endless chase trying to replace these URLs wherever possible because of these issues, so we are looking for alternate solutions. Ideally we would be able to man-in-the-middle all network traffic from client side to redirect it to our servers when the requests are made, so we don't need to deal with preemptively replacing all URLs.

This seems to go against browser security, but since we have control over the static files being sent to the user, we are hoping there is some way to add logic into the html/js files that will redirect all requests to us.

TLDR: Is it possible to include some `script` tag in static files that catch all requests made from the client and allows for those requests to be modified before being sent?

Comment: Why not just cache big static files (generic stylesheets, JS libraries, images, etc.), and let their server handle the dynamic content and non-static files? Would that work...?

Comment: We would like to avoid sending any requests to our client's servers. We aren't trying to replicate the full experience of their site, but rather simulate it via these cached files. Therefore being able to cache and re-serve the dynamic content would be necessary.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe [Service Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API) can be used for this purpose.